# Find the order of this ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> What is the order of differential equation whose general solution is given by $$y=(c_1+c_2)\cos(x+c_3)-c_4e^{x+c_5}+c_5\sin x$$

My answer is coming $4$ but the answer given in the textbook is $3$. Who is correct $?$ Please help.

Comment: You can simplify the above expression to $y=\alpha\sin x+\beta\cos x+\gamma e^x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple trigonometric manipulation and grouping of the terms means that you can rewrite the above formula as
$$y=\alpha\sin x+\beta\cos x+\gamma e^x$$
From $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ you can find that $\pm i$ are roots of the characteristic polynomial, and $e^x$ means that $1$ is also a root. So you have three roots. The characteristic polynomial is $$(\lambda-i)(\lambda+i)(\lambda-1)=0\\\lambda^3-\lambda^2+\lambda-1=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

Applying the Laplace transform we have

$$
\hat y(s) = \frac{c_5-(c_1+c_2)\sin c_3+(c_1+c_2)\cos c_3 s}{s^2+1}-\frac{c_4}{s-1}
$$

or

$$
\hat y(s) = \frac{C_1+ C_2 s}{s^2+1}+\frac{C_3}{s-1}
$$